# Reactjs How would I display a simple error if no data is fetched from api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm struggling to find a way of adding an error message is filteredCountries from an api === 0. How would I best do this is a simple manner? 
Or is there a simple way to route to a 404 page?

I can think along the correct lines it's just not clicking!

```
const CountryList = ({ filteredCountries, isLoading }) => {
  return (
    <div className='card-list'>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader isLoading={isLoading} />
      ) : (
        filteredCountries.map((country) => (
          <>
            <Country
              key={country.name}
              id={country.alpha3Code}
              country={country}
            />
          </>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default CountryList;
```

Comment: check the length of filteredCounties. If its 0 then show error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could form another conditional and check by the filteredCountries' `length`. It technically wouldn't be considered an error per se but from what I understand this is what you wanted:

```
const CountryList = ({ filteredCountries, isLoading }) => {
  return (
    <div className='card-list'>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader isLoading={isLoading} />
      ) : (
        filteredCountries.length ? (
          'No countries found'
        ) : (
          filteredCountries.map((country) => (
            <>
              <Country
                key={country.name}
                id={country.alpha3Code}
                country={country}
              />
            </>
        )))
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default CountryList;
```

Comment: `filteredCountries.length === 0` Worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: Great but just remember: `filteredCountries.length === 0` and `filterCountries.length` are essentially the same if the array is empty. The latter would return `0` so there's no need for the strict equality check.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that! Thanks.